# How to use routes properly in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have app architecture(approximately): (I'm using `Express` framework)

```
-routes
-views
-public
-app.js
```

I tried to use a route in `app.js` in this way:

```
var router = require('routes');
app.get('/', router.get);
app.get('/otherRoute', router.get);
```

File `index.js` in `routes` folder:

```
exports.get = function(req, res) {
   res.render('index',{
       title: "Express",
       a: '<a href="#">Link</a>'
   });
};
```

I generated only this route `'/'`, `'/otherRoute'` also generated by `index.js` of course. I just show the schema.

- How I can use routes in my app properly? I want, for example, that routes handle by separate file (`routes/index.js`, `routes/about.js`, ...). Or will be better to use a one file to handle routes?
- What app architecture I should have?
- Hint me, if you know, materials(*articles*,*books*) for how I can build `node.js` apps.

Thank you.

Comment: The official documentation can be seen here https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router . There is quite a lot of information on the default Express router and how to use it. If you're looking for a custom set of routers, your Router directory needs to have an index.js file which includes all individual routers

Comment: Download this book, Express in Action here. https://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://hackerstribe.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Node.js-Express-in-Action.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiU2dXXjsLTAhXDvRQKHdZaBhAQFggYMAA&usg=AFQjCNF_m_SG4cHvAyaC7laafskVErb9zw&sig2=bC0w-NDMZBnTQB77Mp9Uaw

Comment: @KingBryan, thank you!